# Ability to download only after email supplied

Tags: email

I would like to have a page with downloadable items like PDFs, but I would like the user to be required to insert email details before being able to download the files, although he would be able to view the files available even before providing the email address.

The system must also ask only once for the email, and then maybe keep a cookie so that it won't ask for each download requested.

Is there a plugin or code hack available for this? Thanks

Comment: not sure about email but you could have a look for limiting access to pages and downloads to registered users only

Comment: I would love to see an answer to this question too. I need a similar plugin and don't want to require the user to have to register and create an account on the WP-powered site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a long time looking. The best today seems to be http://wordpress.org/plugins/ss-downloads/ or if you want something more complex, https://easydigitaldownloads.com/