# Download stuff after filling fields?

Tags: custom-field, database

is there a way to restrict a download, but if you fill your details get the file?
I need to create a database with the names, mails, companies and phones for the people that want to download a detailed CV, so I want them to fill all the details and afterwards they can download.

And also be able to see the data filled...

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ability to download only after email supplied](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22834/ability-to-download-only-after-email-supplied)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a plugin like [iThemes Exchange](http://ithemes.com/exchange/) and set the price to $0 so they're essentially "buying" your CV for free. Then you'd have their info in your customer list.

Comment: Will try that one :) thanks if it fits me, will return to post your answer as accepted